# How to get current user in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to get the current user, so I can access fields like their email address.
But I can't do that in asp.net core.
This is my code:

`HttpContext` almost is null in **constructor** of controller.
It's not good to get a user in each action. I want to get the user's information once and save it to  `ViewData`;

```
public DashboardController()
{
    var user = HttpContext.User.GetUserId();
}
```

Comment: Using with MVC or Web APi ?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

```
User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```

**EDIT for constructor**

Below code works:

```
public Controller(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    var userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value 
}
```

**Edit for RTM**

You should register `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }
```

Comment: it works in actions.but i wanna use in constructor of controller.

Comment: is it possible use this in classes?

Comment: because of dependency injection, yes you can use

Comment: `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` gives the current user id, and `ClaimTypes.Name` gives the username.

Comment: Can anybody tell me what is wrong with UserPrincipal.Current.Name?

Comment: this code is not working in IE Edge browser. However same is working everywhere else.

Comment: @ademcaglin For some reasons User is returning `null` in my case? Im using `.Net core 2.1 Web api` though.

Comment: As Nikolay Kostov points out in his comment to this, you only get username and id. If you want the profile information you will have to do this outside the constructor, since it is an async operation (you cannot await inside a constructor).Someone  correct me if it actually is so, that you can get other profile information IPrincipal in constructor

Comment: I am really struggling with this part of ASP.NET Core. Where are you getting `IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor` for your constructor? I'm following MS's [ASP.NET Core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), but it has nothing about this. Where can I get more help?

Answer (score 82):

Simple way that works and I checked.

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
public CompetitionsController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

then you can all the properties of this variables like `user.Email`. I hope this would help someone.

**Edit**:

It's an apparently simple thing but bit complicated cause of different types of authentication systems in ASP.NET Core. I update cause some people are getting `null`.

For JWT Authentication (Tested on ASP.NET Core v3.0.0-preview7):

```
var email = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;

var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
```

Comment: works great for me inside a controller in asp.net Core 2.0

Comment: what is a _userManager?

Comment: In ASP.NET Core Identity, User Manager is a service provided by Dependency Inject to Create Users. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) for more info:

Comment: How can this be achieved in a non-async method?

Comment: For me is returning null. Why?

Comment: @AlbertoCláudioMandlate if you are using JWT validation try `HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;`

Comment: for anyone if its not working , please check answer from @Tom Stickel, Change the launch settings

Comment: @Ahmad if token is created with appropriate claims, then UserManager works with JWT Auth as well.

Comment: GetUserAsync method goes in and comes back. Nothing happens when this method is called. Nothing even returned from like first sentence.

Answer (score 69):

I have to say I was quite surprised that HttpContext is null inside the constructor. I'm sure it's for performance reasons. Have confirmed that using `IPrincipal` as described below does get it injected into the constructor. Its essentially doing the same as the accepted answer, but in a more interfacey-way.

---

For anyone finding this question looking for an answer to the generic *"How to get current user?"* you can just access `User` directly from `Controller.User`. But you can only do this inside action methods (I assume because controllers don't only run with HttpContexts and for performance reasons).

However - if you need it in the constructor (as OP did) or need to create other  injectable objects that need the current user then the below is a better approach:

### Inject IPrincipal to get user

First meet `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`

```
public interface IPrincipal
{
    IIdentity Identity { get; }
    bool IsInRole(string role);
}

public interface IIdentity
{
    string AuthenticationType { get; }
    bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}
```

`IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` represents the user and username. [Wikipedia will comfort you if 'Principal' sounds odd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_(computer_security)).

Important to realize that whether you get it from `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User`, `ControllerBase.User` or `ControllerBase.HttpContext.User` you're **getting an object that is guaranteed to be a `ClaimsPrincipal` object which implements `IPrincipal`**.

There's no other type of User that ASP.NET uses for `User` right now, (but that's not to say other something else couldn't implement `IPrincipal`).

So if you have something which has a dependency of 'the current user name' that you want injected you should be injecting `IPrincipal` and definitely not `IHttpContextAccessor`.

**Important:** Don't waste time injecting `IPrincipal` directly to your controller, or action method - it's pointless since `User` is available to you there already.

In `startup.cs`:

```
// Inject IPrincipal
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(
    provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
```

Then in your DI object that needs the user you just inject `IPrincipal` to get the current user.

The most important thing here is if you're doing unit tests you don't need to send in an `HttpContext`, but only need to mock something that represents `IPrincipal` [which can just be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323895/how-to-add-claims-in-a-mock-claimsprincipal) `ClaimsPrincipal`.

One extra important thing that I'm not 100% sure about. If you need to access the actual claims from `ClaimsPrincipal` you need to cast `IPrincipal` to `ClaimsPrincipal`. This is fine since we know 100% that at runtime it's of that type (since that's what `HttpContext.User` is). I actually like to just do this in the constructor since I already know for sure any `IPrincipal`  will be a `ClaimsPrincipal`.

If you're doing mocking, just [create a `ClaimsPrincipal` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325059/16940) and pass it to whatever takes `IPrincipal`.

Exactly why there is no interface for `IClaimsPrincipal` I'm not sure. I assume MS decided that `ClaimsPrincipal` was just a specialized 'collection' that didn't warrant an interface.

Comment: This allows you to inject the current user anywhere in your application, great answer!

Comment: This doesn't work. I always get `null` for the injected `IPrincipal`. I also needed to add the transient service as `…GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext.User…` (with the `?`) because it would crash otherwise (GetService returned null).

Comment: You can just do `services.AddTransient(provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);` as HttpContext.User is a ClaimsPrincipal.

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO.  Because it embraces the idea that (unlike DotNet-Framework), you INJECT things.  (where in DN-FW you would "grab them from some where, like .Thread or app/web.config etc, etc).

Comment: When using ASP.NET Core, the values of both ClaimsPrincipal.Current and Thread.CurrentPrincipal aren't set. These properties both represent static state, which ASP.NET Core generally avoids. Instead, ASP.NET Core uses dependency injection (DI) to provide dependencies such as the current user's identity. Getting the current user's identity from DI is more testable, too, since test identities can be easily injected.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/claimsprincipal-current?view=aspnetcore-6.0#context-specific-state-instead-of-static-state

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best solution when you want to inject User data into external services. It makes no sense to inject the entire HttpContextAccessor in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

Have another way of getting current user in Asp.NET Core - and I think I saw it somewhere here, on SO ^^

```
// Stores UserManager
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _manager; 

// Inject UserManager using dependency injection.
// Works only if you choose "Individual user accounts" during project creation.
public DemoController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)  
{  
    _manager = manager;  
}

// You can also just take part after return and use it in async methods.
private async Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUser()  
{  
    return await _manager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);  
}  

// Generic demo method.
public async Task DemoMethod()  
{  
    var user = await GetCurrentUser(); 
    string userEmail = user.Email; // Here you gets user email 
    string userId = user.Id;
}
```

That code goes to controller named DemoController. Won't work without both await (won't compile) ;)

Comment: This requires the use of Identity

Comment: What is ApplicationUser?

Comment: ApplicationUser is typically inherited from IdentityUser so it can be extended with additional properties, etc.

Answer (score 27):

It would appear that as of now (April of 2017) that the following works:

```
public string LoggedInUser => User.Identity.Name;
```

At least while within a `Controller`

Comment: You cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Security.Principal.IIdentity' to 'string'.

Comment: string LoggedInUser = User.Identity.Name;

Comment: As someone who hadn't seen the `=>` operator used like this before, it is called an  "Expression Body Definition" and is described in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator). Just in case future people like me are wondering.

Comment: Your code couldn't possibly compile prior to the edit, given that there's no conversion from `IIdentity` to `string`, as also stated in the top comment. The edit simply fixed that. I'm not sure how you reached your conclusion either (in particular since "editor" points are given only to users below 2k reputation).

Answer (score 20):

Perhaps I didn't see the answer, but this is how I do it.

1. **.Net Core --> Properties --> launchSettings.json**

You need to have change these values

```
"windowsAuthentication": true, // needs to be true
"anonymousAuthentication": false,  // needs to be false
```

Startup.cs --> ConfigureServices(...)

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

MVC or Web Api Controller

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
//constructor then
_httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
```

Controller method:

```
string userName = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

Result is userName e.g.  = Domain\username

Comment: This is relevant to hosting too. You need to disable Anonymus Authentification in IIs for this to work.

Answer (score 10):

I know there area lot of correct answers here, with respect to all of them I introduce this hack :

In StartUp.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

and then everywhere you need HttpContext you can use :

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextAccessor().HttpContext;
```

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 6):

My problem was to access the logged in User as an object in the cshtml file. Considering you wanted the user in ViewData, this approach might be helpful:

In the cshtml file

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
    @UserManager.FindByNameAsync(UserManager.GetUserName(User)).Result.Email
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any idea how you might get a navigation property to load (Company name of a company navigation property on my ApplicationUser class).  Didn't see a way to include navigation properties.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to existing answers I'd like to add that you can also have a class instance available app-wide which holds user-related data like `UserID` etc.

It may be useful for **refactoring** *e.g. you don't want to fetch `UserID` in every controller action and declare an extra `UserID` parameter in every method related to Service Layer.*

I've done a research and here's [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51687042/5374333).

You just extend your class which you derive from `DbContext` by adding `UserId` property (or implement a custom `Session` class which has this property).

At filter level you can fetch your class instance and set `UserId` value.

After that wherever you inject your instance - it will have the necessary data (lifetime must be *per request*, so you register it using `AddScoped` method).

Working example:

```
public class AppInitializationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private DBContextWithUserAuditing _dbContext;

    public AppInitializationFilter(
        DBContextWithUserAuditing dbContext
        )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
        ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next
        )
    {
        string userId = null;
        int? tenantId = null;

        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (userIdClaim != null)
        {
            userId = userIdClaim.Value;
        }

        var tenantIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == CustomClaims.TenantId);
        if (tenantIdClaim != null)
        {
            tenantId = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantIdClaim.Value) ? int.Parse(tenantIdClaim.Value) : (int?)null;
        }

        _dbContext.UserId = userId;
        _dbContext.TenantId = tenantId;

        var resultContext = await next();
    }
}
```

For more information see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129616/5374333).

Answer (score 2):

This is old question but my case shows that my case wasn't discussed here.

I like the most the answer of Simon_Weaver (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54411397/2903893). He explains in details how to get user name using IPrincipal and IIdentity. This answer is absolutely correct and I recommend to use this approach. However, during debugging I encountered with the problem when **ASP.NET can NOT populate service principle properly**. (or in other words, IPrincipal.Identity.Name is null)

It's obvious that to get user name MVC framework should take it from somewhere. In the .NET world, ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core is using Open ID Connect middleware.
In the simple scenario web apps authenticate a user in a web browser. In this scenario, the web application directs the user’s browser to sign them in to Azure AD. Azure AD returns a sign-in response through the user’s browser, which contains claims about the user in a security token. 
To make it work in the code for your application, you'll need to provide the authority to which you web app delegates sign-in. 
When you deploy your web app to Azure Service the common scenario to meet this requirements is to configure web app: "App Services" -> YourApp -> "Authentication / Authorization" blade -> "App Service Authenticatio" = "On" and so on (https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-api/app-service-api-authentication.md). I beliebe (this is my educated guess) that under the hood of this process the wizard adjusts "parent" web config of this web app by adding the same settings that I show in following paragraphs.
Basically, the issue why this approach does NOT work in ASP.NET Core is because "parent" machine config is ignored by webconfig. (this is not 100% sure, I just give the best explanation that I have). So, to meke it work you need to setup this manually in your app.

Here is an article that explains how to manyally setup your app to use Azure AD.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore2-2

Step 1: Register the sample with your Azure AD tenant.
(it's obvious, don't want to spend my time of explanations).

Step 2: In the appsettings.json file:
replace the ClientID value with the Application ID from the application you registered in Application Registration portal on Step 1.
replace the TenantId value with common

Step 3: Open the Startup.cs file and in the ConfigureServices method, after the line containing .AddAzureAD insert the following code, which enables your application to sign in users with the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, that is both Work and School and Microsoft Personal accounts.

```
services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
{
    options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
});
```

**Summary**: I've showed one more possible issue that could leed to an error that topic starter is explained. The reason of this issue is missing configurations for Azure AD (Open ID middleware). In order to solve this issue I propose manually setup "Authentication / Authorization". The short overview of how to setup this is added.

Answer (score 1):

Taking `IdentityUser` would also work. This is a current user object and all values of user can be retrieved.

```
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
public yourController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the scafolded **Identity** and using Asp.net Core 2.2+ you can access the current user from a view like this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

 @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <p>Hello @User.Identity.Name!</p>
    }
    else
    {
        <p>You're not signed in!</p>
    }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers show how to best handle `HttpContext` from the documentation, which is also what I went with.

I did want to mention that you'll want to check you project settings when debugging, the default is `Enable Anonymous Authentication = true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (access token in header or query parameter)
{
    // Set the claims like in the Account/Login action from the interactive login form
    var claims = ...;
    // Local helper method, is used in other places, too
    var claimsIdentity = await SignInAsync(httpContext, claims, false);
    // Set user for the current request
    // This works in that it's in User.Identity, but the auth events won't fire
    httpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
}
```

And

```
var userEmail = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

After exploring many solutions, here is what worked for me with ASP.NET core 5.

```
        var claims = new List<Claim>(){
            new Claim("Id", _user.Id)
        };
```

As shown in the above snippet, add custom "Id" type and set it to user id while preparing list of claims to be included in the Jwt Token generation.
Then simply use that claim to access the user(This method uniquely identifies the user by its Id).

```
        var userEmail = User.FindFirstValue("Id");
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userEmail);
```

Here is complete solution:
->Token generation helper method

```
        public async Task<string> CreateToken()
        {
            var signingCredentials = GetSigningCredentials();
            var claims = await GetClaims();
            var tokenOptions = GenerateTokenOptions(signingCredentials, claims);
            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokenOptions);
        }
    
        private SigningCredentials GetSigningCredentials()
        {
            var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JWT_SECRET"));
            var secret = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
            return new SigningCredentials(secret, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        }
        private async Task<List<Claim>> GetClaims()
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>(){
                new Claim("Id", _user.Id)
            };
            return claims;
        }
        private JwtSecurityToken GenerateTokenOptions(SigningCredentials signingCredentials, List<Claim> claims)
        {
            var jwtSettings = _configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings");
            var tokenOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: jwtSettings.GetSection("ValidIssuer").Value,
                audience: jwtSettings.GetSection("ValidAudience").Value,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(jwtSettings.GetSection("ExpiresIn").Value)),
                signingCredentials: signingCredentials,
                claims: claims
            );
            return tokenOptions;
        }
```

Here is code for Getting LoggedIn User:

```
        [HttpGet("user")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<User>> GetUser()
        {
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue("Id");
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            return Ok(new { User = User });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use answer provided by @Ahmed for Identity

For getting the current user id, I use the following

```
 var currentuserid = userManager.GetUserId(User);
```

For getting other fields related to logged user in AspNetUsers table, I use the following

```
var userorg = context.Users.Where(l=>l.Id== currentuserid).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result.OrganizationId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want you can get id on claim like here

```
   var userId = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting to get the current user of an ASP.NET C# Web application - even when running on IIS I have personally validated this solution after hours of trying many other options mentioned in my research.

```
  string userName = User.Identity.Name;
```

Please be sure that Authentication for web app on IIS includes Windows Authentication.
Also, be sure that your Program.cs file includes...

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddNegotiate();
    
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
        options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    });
```

Comment: @Mehran Hafizi, Please explain how your edits improved my solution and why you voted down my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Doug ,I haven't voted down it at all! I only fixed some style issues.

Comment: OH. Sorry Mehran. Sometimes these messages and such are confusing. Just wanted to know how to improve my answers. Have a grate day!

Answer (score 0):

Reviving this ancient post as it came up on my google searches for the same problem but none of the solutions offered here appeared to work for our scenario.

We are using identity 3 in an ASP.Net Core Web Application (generated from the template).

To get the `ApplicationUser` in a controller we had to do

```cs
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
```

where `_userManager` is an `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` injected in through DI in the constructor of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple projects referencing one on the other:

```
Web -> Core -> Persistence
```

I'm using a custom claim in a JWT Token for the `MyUser` object.

I wanted to get the current user for the current request in `Persistence`, there is no reference to the current request to be able to get the user.

So here is what I did. The `MyUser` object lives in the `Persistence` project, so I added an Interface `IMyUserProvider` to the `Persistence` project:

```
namespace Persistence;

public interface IMyUserProvider
{
    public MyUser User { get; }
}
```

Then in `StartUp` (in `Web`) I added a `Scoped Service` (meaning this only lives for the current `Request`):

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IMyUserProvider>(provider =>
{
    var httpContextAccessor = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

    var userClaim = httpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "myUser");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userClaim?.Value))
    {
        return JsonExtensions.DeserializeFromJson<MyUser>(userClaim?.Value);
    }

    return null;
});
```

Finally I implemented the `IMyUserProvider` on `MyUser`:

```
public class MyUser : IMyUserProvider
{
    //...

    //Added JsonIgnore to prevent JsonSerializer from getting loop reference error
    //when creating the Token for MyUser in the first place.
    [JsonIgnore]
    public MyUser User => this;

    //...
}
```

Now using Dependency Injection in any project gets me the `MyUser` instance:

```
namespace Persistence;

public class SomePersistenceService
{
    public SomePersistenceService(IMyUserProvider myUserProvider)
    {
        MyUser user = myUserProvider.User;
    }
}
```

*I'm using `.Net 7`*

Answer (score -1):

I got my solution

```
var claim = HttpContext.User.CurrentUserID();

public static class XYZ
{
    public static int CurrentUserID(this ClaimsPrincipal claim)
    {
        var userID = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList().Find(r => r.Type == 
         "UserID").Value;
        return Convert.ToInt32(userID);
    }
    public static string CurrentUserRole(this ClaimsPrincipal claim)
    {
        var role = claimsPrincipal.Claims.ToList().Find(r => r.Type == 
        "Role").Value;
        return role;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.