# ASP.NET Core Entity changing history

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, audit-logging, audit.net

I have many controllers like this:

```cs
public class EntityController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEntityRepository _entity;

    public EntityController(IEntityRepository entity)
    {
        _entity = entity;
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async ValueTask<IActionResult> Put(int id, [FromBody] Entity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null || entity.Id != id) return BadRequest();
        var updated = await _entity.Update(entity);
        if (updated == null) return NotFound();
        return Ok(updated);
    }
}
```

I need to implement entities editing (audit) history.

And, since the method is marked as `[Authorize]`, I need to log by which user it was edited.
I'm looking at `Audit.NET`, but I didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: One way would be to use an action filter, either in OnActionExecuting or OnActionExecuted.  Something like https://gist.github.com/mgroves/1832983 should get you started.

Comment: But how can I save (oldvalue, newvalue, username)? Its just a trigger

Comment: You get username from context, i.e. ```context.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name``` and parameters from ```context.ActionArguments```.  Assuming you have the PK in the model you can lookup the old values.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but maybe try the [audit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.Audit.EFCore/) component of 
Entity Framework Plus instead which has some good [examples](http://entityframework-plus.net/audit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Audit.NET [EF Provider](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#entity-framework-data-provider) allows to customize the audit entity  before saving it. This has to be done at the startup with a so-called [AuditEntity Action](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md#ef-provider-options): an action that is triggered for each entity being modified.

So, you can make this action retrieve the user name from the current `HttpContext` and store it in a `UserName` property on your audit entities.

On your asp net startup code, setup a way to obtain the current `HttpContext` and configure the action to retrieve the username from the context:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add the HttpContextAccessor if needed.
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        // Get the service provider to access the http context
        var svcProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        // Configure Audit.NET
        Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
            .UseEntityFramework(x => x
                .AuditTypeNameMapper(typeName => "Audit_" + typeName)
                .AuditEntityAction((evt, ent, auditEntity) =>
                {
                    // Get the current HttpContext 
                    var httpContext = svcProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
                    // Store the identity name on the "UserName" property of the audit entity
                    ((dynamic)auditEntity).UserName = httpContext.User?.Identity.Name;
                }));
    }
}
```

This is assuming your audit entities have a common `UserName` property.

If your Audit Entities already inherits from an interface or base class including the UserName, you can use the generic `AuditEntityAction<T>` instead.

```
Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
    .UseEntityFramework(x => x
        .AuditTypeNameMapper(typeName => "Audit_" + typeName)
        .AuditEntityAction<IUserName>((evt, ent, auditEntity) =>
        {
            var httpContext = svcProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
            auditEntity.UserName = httpContext.User?.Identity.Name;
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

To get UserID in IOC :

```
var userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
```

[how-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core)