# User.Identity.Name returns null in ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Please check the code below. This is a controller of my ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application.

Problem is that I am already using cookie authenticated user, but the `User.Identity.Name` returns null. How can I get my current auth user on .NET Core then?

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddMainMenu(MainMenuItems mainMenuItems)
{
      string userEmail = User.Identity.Name;
      return Json("success");          
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it-

```
var val = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
```

If your claim NameIdentifier is Email then do like above. This should work. More information [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).