# SignInAsync verifies authenticated cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

This [document](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-identity-tutorial/) says:

> We are invoking **PasswordSignInAsync**to verify and issue an
>   authentication cookie

Does this method really verify the authenticated cookie?
What does it when it does verify, how can i fetch the result of said Verification?

In other words: What is the best method to know that a user is signed in in identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...verify the authenticated cookie

That's not how that sentence is meant to be read, I would assume.

[PasswordSignInAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.passwordsigninasync) verifies the credentials that are passed to it, and if they are valid, it creates the authentication cookie and adds it to the response.

> ...method to know that a user is signed in in identity

The authentication cookie is used to recreate the Identity and Principal objects on each request, so the simple answer to your question is

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated // this is a Boolean value
```

If you want to stick with the SignInManager, use [IsSignedIn()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinmanager-1.issignedin), which would be called like this:

```
// Assuming you have an instance of SignInManager called _signInManager
_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User);
```

You probably want to review something like [How get current user in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core)