# use the Identity as filtermechanism in my Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a Controller that grabs all the items from a Mysql database and puts them into my models.
This method is called in my Index() so it can display all the items in a gridview.

I want to be able to sign in on the webpage with a 'company number' that is used in the Login.cshtml.
The company number also needs to be used in my Contoller ( I think ). It will be used in the SQL Query so the company only sees their own items.
but how can I make it so the Controller is able to reach the information?

```
public List<ContainerInfo> TablesColumnDisplay()
{
  //string on = the connectionstring
  using SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM TheItemList"); //I think this needs WHERE company_number = '{Identity.Companynumber}'
  using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
      {
        SqlComm.Connection = SqlConn;
        SqlConn.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = SqlComm;

        SqlDataReader sdr = SqlComm.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
          ItemList item = new ItemList();
          //The entire sdr reader that puts all the items into the models
        }
}
```

Or am I horribly wrong and do I have to make a deperate method for it? I'm a bit lost on how to attack this problem.

**Edit**
I am using the standard scaffolded Identity Area where i've changed some model items.
in my Login.cshtml is a standard form which is asking for company_number, password and if a remember me is true or not.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.company_number.ToString(), Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

Comment: Is this an action method, why not pass the company number as a query parameter?

Comment: Could you share the login view?

Comment: The DropdownColumns is a List. it generates all information from an SQL query and I pass this through the Index() method via ViewData. ```public IActionResult Index()         {             ViewData["DropDown1"] = DropdownMenu();             var containers = _context.B0.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rowid);             return View(containers);         }```  I am currently using the standard scaffolded Razorpage Login.cshtml and login.cshtml.cs where I changed Emailed to 'company_number

Comment: I think such a long question can sum up in this a few words "*How to get_company number of current logged in user?*"

Comment: How to get the company_number from a logged in user to my Controller and use it in my TablesColumnDisplay() method. that is is what should probably happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by looking through stackoveflow.

Note that I have to use 'System.Security.Claims' in order to access the Logged user.
You need a variable which contains the currently logged in user. this can be found with User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value; [Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core)

You can then use that variable in your SQL query by using the $ sign at the start. allowing you to use variables inside of the query.

```
using System.Security.Claims;

//This gives me the value of the first ClaimTypes.Name(which in my case: is 123456)
int Username = Convert.ToInt32(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value);
public List<ContainerInfo> TablesColumnDisplay()
{
  //string conn = the connectionstring
  using SqlCommand SqlComm = new SqlCommand($"SELECT * FROM TheItemList WHERE company_number = {Username}"); 
  using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
      {
        SqlComm.Connection = SqlConn;
        SqlConn.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = SqlComm;

        SqlDataReader sdr = SqlComm.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
          ItemList item = new ItemList();
          //The entire sdr reader that puts all the items into the models
        }
}
```