# How to send SignalR notifications to specific user in ASP.NET Core (MVC) with Windows Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, windows-authentication

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web application. The application uses Windows Authentication. I want to send notifications to the client side from an API controller once it receives a post request. I found this resource https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0) that says I need to use a CustomUserIdProvider to get the Id of tat specific user. However, I'm not sure how should I call the following method:

```
_myHub.Clients.User(specificUserId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
```

How can I get that specificUserId in my API controller. I tried injecting the CustomUserIdProvider and then calling this method:

```
_myHub.Clients.User(_customUserIdProvider.GetUserId(conn)).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
```

However I don't know how do I get the HubConnectionContext conn object that is required by the GetUserId method from this API controller.

This is the CustomUserIdProvider class:

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User?.Identity?.Name;
    }
}
```

In case this doesn't work, is there any other way in which one can send SignalR notifications to specific users authenticated with Windows Authentication to an ASP.NET MVC web application? Thanks!

Comment: Don't you store this ids (or get them from incoming post request)? I mean.. how could you now to whom exactly you will have to send this message after all?

Comment: I was thinking of sending the [Domain]\[Username] in the post request. Then if I can get all the connections Ids generated by the customUserIdProvider, I could map those usernames with their corresponding connectionId. But, how could I get those connection Ids in my API controller by using that customeUserIdProvider method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to pass the instance of the CustomUserIdProvider to the hub. The IUserIdProvider defines what happens behind the scenes on how the SignalR returns the userId and identifies the users.

You register your CustomUserIdProvider

```
services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();
```

The point of this is to match the user id you will provide to the user id it looks for in its list of users.

Then if you are trying to do this in a controller and not a hub I assume you can do:

```
public Controller(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
   _userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
}
```

As seen in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36641907/2490286

and then

```
_myHub.Clients.User(_userId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @misha130! It worked just perfectly fine!. I just needed to change the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier to ClaimTypes.Name since the first one returned null. Then I changed _userId to message.username within the _myHub.Clients.User(message.username) method as suggested by @Timur Umerov.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the actual connection. If you are sending username with post request, just take that username and pass it here

```
_myHub.Clients.User(Username).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
```

or if it is contained inside a message object

```
_myHub.Clients.User(message.Username).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
```

**UPDATE**

If the format of the string you are getting with `connection.User?.Identity?.Name` in your `CustomUserIdProvider` is `[Domain][Username]`, then you should be fine passing that through Post request and then using it in `User()` method.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works but just after using the mapping generated by _userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value; as was suggested by @misha130.