# Accessing LogonUserIdentity data from ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

In a previous application, I had the need to grab the LogonUserIdentity.Name value from the HttpContext as the user his the controller route. This application was a .NET Framework ASP.NET Web API, and I did this in the following way:

```
var username = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

This returned domain\username of the user hitting the route. I want to access this value in a new application, but this application is a .NET 6 ASP.NET Core Web API. I have tried to simply access through the HttpContext with this:

```
var username = HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name
```

This value returns null, however. My program.cs is as follows:

```
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddCors(options => {

options.AddPolicy(name: "corsPolicy",

policy => {

policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "localhost")

.AllowAnyHeader()

.AllowAnyMethod()

.AllowCredentials();

});

});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())

{

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseCors("corsPolicy");

}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Is there a way to grab this value in .NET Core?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current user in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @derloopkat Unfortunately the accepted answer of this did not work. Adding `var user = _context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value` to my controller route throws an exception, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: You should be able to use var username = User.Identity.Name;  If that returns null, you probably need to setup some things in IIS, and webconfig to make sure anonymous is not allowed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Have you registered the authentication related services?username would be accessed only after you've authenticated