# My httpcontext.user always return null in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**My HttpContext.User always return null**

I have login method that implement login logic and return accessToken, refreshToken

```
public async Task<LoginResponseDto> Login(LoginDto loginDto)
    {
        var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Email == loginDto.Email);
        if (user is null)
            throw new Exception("The user is not valid");
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
            user.UserName,
            loginDto.Password,
            true,
            false
        );
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return new LoginResponseDto()
            {
                IsLoginSuccessful = false,
                ErrorMessage = "Invalid Authentication"
            };
        }

        var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
        var accessToken = _jwtHandler.GenerateAccessToken(claims);
        var refreshToken = _jwtHandler.GenerateRefreshToken();
        return new LoginResponseDto() { AccessToken = accessToken, RefreshToken = refreshToken };
    }
}
```

Then i create post and assign the property post.UserId by getting it from httpcontext

```
public async Task<Post> CreatePost(CreatePostDto createPostDto)
    {
        var userId = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(
            nameof(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
        );

        var post = _mapper.Map<CreatePostDto, Post>(createPostDto);
        if (createPostDto is { FileUpload: not null })
        {
            var filePath = await GenerateFilePath(createPostDto.FileUpload);
            post.MainImage = filePath;
        }

        post.UserId = userId;
        _context.Posts.Add(post);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return post;
    }
```

I have authorize in swagger the access token and have tested this token in jwt and it work fine
the problem just is httpcontext.user of mine can't get the current user :((

Also, this is my register method logic

```
 public async Task Register(RegisterDto model)
    {
        var user = _mapper.Map<RegisterDto, User>(model);
        user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            throw new Exception(
                $"Your username {user.UserName} or email {user.Email} have been used"
            );
        }
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new(nameof(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier), $"{user.Id}"),
            new(nameof(ClaimTypes.Role), $"{model.SetRole.ToString()}"),
            new(nameof(ClaimTypes.Name), $"{user.UserName}")
        };
        await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);
    }
```

Edit: My program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.ConfigurationServices();
builder.RegisterDependencyInjection();
builder.RegisterService();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddIdentityApi();

var app = builder.Build();

// app.RegisterEndpointDefinitions();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.AddSwagger();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

//app.ExceptionHandler();

app.MiddlewareHandler();
app.Run();
```

My BlogApiExtension.cs

```
public static class BlogApiExtension
{
    public static void RegisterDependencyInjection(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostRepository, PostRepository>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IJwtHandler, JwtHandler>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IFileService, FileService>();

        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(CreatePost.Command).Assembly);
        });
        builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(RegisterUser.Command).Assembly);
        });
        builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(PostProfile), typeof(UserProfile));
    }

    public static void RegisterService(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var userConnectionString = SecretService.GetSecret($"{nameof(Secret.blogsql)}");

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(userConnectionString));

        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddCors();
    }

    public static void AddIdentityApi(this IServiceCollection service)
    {
        var jwtSecret = SecretService.GetSecret($"{nameof(Secret.jwtsecret)}");

        service
            .AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(
                options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
            )
            .AddSignInManager()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>();

        service
            .AddAuthentication(options => options.ConfigureAuthOptions())
            .AddJwtBearer(options => options.ConfigureBearerOption(jwtSecret));
        service.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AddIdentityOptions();
        });

        service.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.AddSwaggerAuth());
    }

    #region exception handler

    public static void ExceptionHandler(this WebApplication app)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(
            exception =>
                exception.Run(async context =>
                {
                    var exceptionHandlerFeaturePath =
                        context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
                    var err = exceptionHandlerFeaturePath?.Error;
                    if (err is ConflictException)
                    {
                        await Results.Conflict().ExecuteAsync(context);
                        return;
                    }

                    await Results.Problem().ExecuteAsync(context);
                })
        );
    }

    #endregion

    #region middleware

    public static void MiddlewareHandler(this WebApplication app)
    {
        app.Use(
            async (context, next) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await next(context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is ConflictException)
                        await Results.Conflict().ExecuteAsync(context);

                    throw;
                }
            }
        );
    }

    #endregion

    public static void AddSwagger(this WebApplication app)
    {
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            return;
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    public static void ConfigurationServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var keyVaultUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration.GetSection("KeyVaultURL").Value!);
        var azureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultUrl, azureCredential);
    }
}
```

IdentityConfig.cs

```
public static class IdentityConfig
{
    public static void ConfigureAuthOptions(this AuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }

    public static void AddIdentityOptions(this IdentityOptions options)
    {
        options.Password = new PasswordOptions
        {
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireNonAlphanumeric = false
        };
        options.User = new UserOptions()
        {
            AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+",
            RequireUniqueEmail = true,
        };
        options.Lockout = new LockoutOptions() { AllowedForNewUsers = true };
    }
}
```

JwtHelper.cs

```
public static class JwtHelper
{
    private static TokenValidationParameters GetTokenValidationParameters(string jwtSecret)
    {
        return new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSecret)),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            RequireExpirationTime = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    }

    public static void ConfigureBearerOption(this JwtBearerOptions options, string jwtSecret)
    {
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = GetTokenValidationParameters(jwtSecret);
    }
}
```

SwaggerConfig.cs

```
public static class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void AddSwaggerAuth(this SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        options.AddSecurityDefinition(
            "Bearer",
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
            {
                Description =
                    "JWT Authorization header using Bearer scheme. Enter just your token in the text input below",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Scheme = "bearer",
                Name = "Authorization",
                BearerFormat = "JWT"
            }
        );
        options.AddSecurityRequirement(
            new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference()
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

edit 2: I test it in postman and it return this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWZtN.png)

but in jwt it work fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy7OJ.png)

this is my project github link as well: https://github.com/khauvannam/BlogProject.Server.git

Try to get current user through httpcontext.user in other controller

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current user in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641338/how-to-get-current-user-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I have seen this post, thanks but the problem still isn't solved

Comment: please share your startup.cs

Comment: @Lee I have edited my question to provide the program.cs, can u review it and help me

Comment: Tested with your code sample(without Azure part) and user got . Can you please add breakpoints to check if user mapped correctly and give more debug details .

Comment: Why are you using `nameof` whenever you need to pass claim type? For example: `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"` but `nameof(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) = "NameIdentifier"`.

Comment: @Ronaldoz yeb, i have check this and everything is ok, actually when i test with string which is userid in my database replace to httpcontext.user, it work perfectly, so the problem is httpcontext.user

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos i like the claim which name is nameidentity, it look clear

Comment: @Ronaldoz u take it from my github, right? Can i have your inbox?

Comment: @Ronaldoz if you are free, please reply my comment, i stuck in this 3 days :(((, if can, will i have your contact , facebook, telegram...

Comment: There is a chance asp.net core parses your token in C# and cannot recognize the claim , but I can't reproduce it . Please check this way .

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting this on IIS, the server needs to have anonymous authentication disabled and windows authentication enabled.

If you are trying to run it locally and it still doesn't work add to your services the httpContextAccessor:

```
builder.services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

and AddAuthentication if you are hosting the app on IIS

```
builder.services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

After that try getting the username with this:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name
```